# making a progress dialog stop when clicking on back activity in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have 3 edittexts and a button.I have implemented progress dialog on button click.I want to stop a dialog on pressing back button,But that progress dialog is not dismissing,,,,I have tried dismissing,finishing dialog,,but of no use

I have tried setcancellable false,,,,its not working

Code is

http://pastie.org/4251606

can anyone suggest me,,,

Thanks in advance
TUshar

Comment: Can you try [overriding the back button][1] (at your own risk) and then dismiss the dialog there?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity

Answer (score 1):

Try setcancellable true........