# Back button of android device not working in rhomobile

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I am new to rhomobile. I have created sample application for 3 screens. I am trying to use back button of device to redirect previous screens. But back button is not working. It remains on same screens. Also when we at first screen I want to close application on back button of device.
Can we do that programatically?

Comment: did you override the onBackPressed Button?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity

Comment: @sammer, I am implemenating back button in rhomobile.

Answer (score 1):

Very late response but may be useful for people when they come to this post.

In android (this doesn't appear to work for Windows Mobile) you would use

```
 render :back => url
```

Where url is the url that you wish to proceed back to

Link for the brief documentation on this:

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/ui#redefine-back-action

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code?
Here is the back button example using meta tags

```
<META HTTP-Equiv="BackButton" Content="Visibility:Visible">
<META HTTP-Equiv="BackButton" Content="Left:50">
<META HTTP-Equiv="BackButton" Content="Top:50">
<META HTTP-Equiv="BackButton" Content="Width:30">
<META HTTP-Equiv="BackButton" Content="Height:30">
```

[Back Button](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/backbutton)

Quit button:

```
<META HTTP-Equiv="QuitButton" Content="Visibility:Visible">
<META HTTP-Equiv="QuitButton" Content="Left:50">
<META HTTP-Equiv="QuitButton" Content="Top:50">
```

Here is the link how to the quit button:

[Quit Button](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/quitbutton)