# is there anyway to make MyService don't get destroy when user close app?

Tags: android, service, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Well lets say that I have a service that plays your music (like Google Music) my service works perfectly, but if the user exit the app , pressing back button or removing it from recents, my service call onDestroy wait ~5secs and calls onCreate again.

So the question is, how I can make it stay alive until the user close it with a button?
(Just like Gogle Music does)

Comment: I think you should search for your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity

Comment: That won't help since the user can exit the app removing it from recent apps. So the service got killed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start your service as foreground using `Service.startForeground`

Comment: interesting, I never thought about that. Will test it and report back.