# Override onBackkeyPressed() to a layout visible or invisible

Tags: android

I am trying to take control of the back button of my phone and set a layout visible invisible when pressed back key but nothing appear. I wonder if its possible to do so.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent ev) {

    switch(keyCode) {

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

        if (main_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

           finish();

        } else if (sub_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

            boutton_radio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            boutton_radio.setEnabled(true);

            sub_layout.setEnabled(false);

            sub_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            main_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            main_layout.setEnabled(true);
        }


    return true;

    }
    return false;

    }
```

Using on backey pressed too give the same result

@Override

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: its alike  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path. :)

```
public void onBackPressed() {

if (main_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

       finish();

    } else if (sub_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

        boutton_radio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        boutton_radio.setEnabled(true);

        sub_layout.setEnabled(false);

        sub_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        main_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        main_layout.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you have `onKeyDown` overwritten as well? Are you sure the conditions are properly met as you'd expect them to be?

Comment: no i use only one of these two methods. not both in the same class

Comment: i have suggest one link in that they are not return true or false and remove something else. once see. its work for me

Comment: So are you overriding `onBackPressed` or `onKeyDown` ?

Answer (score 0):

yah I it should work. I used it to do another function and it will work for you too.
This is how I called a alert box to be called on back key pressed.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final MediaPlayer areusure = MediaPlayer.create(TalkingWebBrowserActivity.this, R.raw.areusure);
        areusure.start();
        AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Do you want to exit the Browser?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                finish();

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                           }
        })
          .show();

    }
```

Comment: He is not asking about how to add dialog in backpressed please read question first !!!

Answer (score 0):

Why u checking two different things in ur if else. If u put in ur else if(main_layout.getVisability  instead of sub main. Try it and tell me if that solved or no