# Android Overriding onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-intent, event-handling, overriding

Is it possible to override `onBackPressed()` for only one activity ?

On back button click I want to call a dialog on a specific Activity, but in all other activities i want it to work as it worked before (going to previous activities).

**EDITED**

Thank you everyone for your answers, I already had everything like you told me, but my problem was that when i was clicking back button on another Activity, I was going to my previous Activity (The one where i had back button Overridden) and i thought that it wasn't working, i thought it was overriding `onBackPressed()` in whole Application, now i got it.

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3142471/2345913)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Yes. Only override it in that one `Activity` with

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

don't put this code in any other `Activity`

Comment: How above code work in fragment? Is this any solutions

Comment: hello i have a same problem my activity 2 is going on activity 1 but i do not want to go activity 1 if i clicked back on activity 2 my application should exit. how can i do that ?

Comment: @Tabishkhan just call `finish()` on activity 1 after starting the intent for activity 2. Then, activity 2 will be the only one in the stack

Comment: @codeMagic how we can reduce duplication of this method? mean I want the same functionality for 5 activities when they click back. So how I can use the same functionality in all activities?

Comment: @UnKnown create an activity to extend in your others and put the code in that super activity

Comment: @codeMagic how I will access the field of child class in the super activity? which I will use in the `onBackPressed()`

Comment: @UnKnown if it does the same thing for all then, ideally, it will contain everything it needs to complete. You may be better off creating a question with the relevant code and what isn't working as expected. There may be a better way but this was my first thought.

Comment: @codeMagic here I have asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906688/how-to-reuse-the-code-for-android

Comment: @codeMagic `super.onBackPressed();` not an option because without this the activity does not return to a previous screen.

Comment: Leave it empty if you want to prevent going back to previous activity.

Answer (score 44):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method as per the example by codeMagic, and remove the call to `super.onBackPressed();` if you do not want the default action (finishing the current activity) to be executed.

Answer (score 6):

OnBackPressed Deprecated.

Kotlin solution here:

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            /* override back pressing */
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                //Your code here
            }
        })
```

Comment: This answer provides the new approach introduced with Android 13 (SDK 33).
You may find more details here [stackoverflow - onBackPressed() deprecated, What is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634225/onbackpressed-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) and a migration guide at [Medium - How To Migrate The Deprecated OnBackPressed Function](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/how-to-migrate-the-deprecated-onbackpressed-function-e66bb29fa2fd).

Answer (score 5):

You may just call the onBackPressed()and if you want some activity to display after the back button you have mention the

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPinActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `onBackPressed()` method in the activity you want to show the dialog and inside it show your dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following code with initializing a field

```
private int count = 0;
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    count++;
    if (count >=1) {
        /* If count is greater than 1 ,you can either move to the next 
        activity or just quit. */
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition
        (R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
        /* Quitting */
        finishAffinity();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to Leave!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // resetting the counter in 2s
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                count = 0;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and most generic way to control the music is to create a mother Activity in which you override `startActivity(Intent intent)` - in it you put `shouldPlay=true`,
and `onBackPressed()` - in it you put `shouldPlay = true`.
`onStop` - in it you put a conditional mediaPlayer.stop with shouldPlay as condition

Then, just extend the mother activity to all other activities, and no code duplicating is needed.

Answer (score 0):

At first you must consider that if your activity which I called A extends another activity  (B) and in both of

them you want to use onbackpressed function then every code you have in B runs in A too. So if you want to separate these you should separate them. It means that A should not extend B , then you can have onbackpressed separately for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Its working

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
         Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Kotlin solution,
Create an extension function below

```kotlin
fun Fragment.onBackPressed(
    navigateToHomeGraph: () -> Unit
) {
    val onBackPressedDispatcher = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                navigateToHomeGraph()
            }
        }
     )
}
```

Now you can simply call this on your Fragment and pass your desired destination.

```kotlin
onBackPressed {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.destination_nav_graph)
}
```