# How to close app if user presses back button on dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I am new to Android and developing a utility UI component which displays dialog box on launch , I want to close the app if user does not make a choice in the dialog box and chooses to press back button. How do I achieve this in dialogFragment? I would not have access to the activity code .

This component is implemented as DialogFragment.

I tried

```
    dialog.setOnDismissListener( new OnDismissListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
```

but this does not close the activity if I press back button.

what is the best practice to implement mandatory dialog box in Android

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a login dialog?  I'm not sure why you wouldn't want the user to open up the application.  You want to Override `onBackPressed()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed

Comment: Yes , this is a login dialogFragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a flag true when open the dialog...
2. onBackPressed() check if the flag true...
3. if true finish the activity...

I haven't tested but it may work ...

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
{
            ((YourActivity)getActivity()).finish();
}
```

If the above one not working ... create a method in your activity for example ...

```
public void closeActivity(){

finish();

}
```

then call the function closeActivity() onDismiss

```
 @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
                ((YourActivity)getActivity()).closeActivity();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I don't have control over activity code , is there any way to achieve this through dialogFragment?