# webview activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have two activity let A and B. A is listActivity and B is webViewActivity. Now in webview, when i back pressed then it works fine within webview but in last back pressed, it resides in activity B but  I want to go back to Activity A (listActivity). 
My code for back pressed

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webView.canGoBack()){
                    webView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about to implement `onBackPressed(.....)` in Activity

Comment: @MD I think onBackPressed and onKeyDown(with KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) are same. if i am wrong plese correct me and what i have to write in onBackPressed().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Overriding onBackPressed()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed)

Comment: @MD public void onBackPressed() {
         if(webView.canGoBack()) {
             webView.goBack();
         } else {
             
             super.onBackPressed();
         }
     }
its not fulfil my requirement. Its working same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you...

http://rickluna.com/wp/2014/04/disable-android-back-button-in-inappbrowser/

here it explains that you can disable back button in webview... so make this works in your logic.

Answer (score -3):

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

         super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

onbackpressed function call when you pressed back button then finish current activity.

Comment: Overriding a method and providing an implementation where you call the method in the super class is complete nonsense. This does absolutely nothing useful.