# Show dialog when user used back button on device

Tags: android, android-dialog

Currently I have an application that has the following code. If the user doesnt save the project before clicking the back button, I provide a dialog box to see if they want to save it prior to exiting the activity.

```
  case android.R.id.home:
      if(!didWeSave){
          SHOW THE DIALOG BOX WITH OPTIONS
      } else {
         NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
      }
   return true;
```

Right now, it only works properly when the user hits on the back arrow from within the application. However, it does not work when I hit the back button on the physical device. How would this be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: [Are you overriding onBackPressed()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed/18337567#18337567)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Overriding the `onBackPressed()` of your activity, and showing the dialog there.

Comment: This will do it. I will accept your answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //SHOW THE DIALOG BOX WITH OPTIONS
}
```

in your activity

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are right, but for completion, You have to comment out super(), to avoid activity is closing without user interaction on Your dialog and provide window leaks.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

 //do Your stuff here
   showDialog();

 //comment out super() here
 //super.onBackPressed();

}
```