# How to go previous Activity by using back button

Tags: android

I have created two activity i.e Activity A & Activity B ,if i clicked Next Button i.e  in Activity A going to Activity B properly But when i click on back button i want to go from Activity B to Activity A  and page swipe from left side to right side and on click next page swipe right to left,

here is my code

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  finish();
```

Comment: Just use finish() no need for intent as A is already in stack and when you finish B, A will come to surface

Comment: thanks man for your response

Comment: @RachitaNanda is not a MAN :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Go back to previous activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)

Comment: @RachitaNanda i did used your way but after apply that if i click back button exit from app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove finish() from `Activity`.

Because when you go to second activity and finish first activity, there is no any activity and stack.

So If you click back button from second activity, application will be finish if there is no Activity in stack.

You should use this Approach.

Ex.

**In Activity.java**

```
Intent first = new Intent(Activity.this,ActivityB.class);
startAcivity(first);
// Don't use finish() here.
```

**In ActivityB.Java**

Just click on built in back button.

or If you want to use your own back button.

Use **finish();** in button click event.

Comment: thanks this is very helpful for me ,thanks again @Chirag

Comment: Welcome. Happy 2 help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only `onBackPressed();`

```
   public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

> [Android Overriding onBackPressed()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed)
>
> [How to go previous Activity by using back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305929/how-to-go-previous-activity-by-using-back-button)

Comment: I thinkno need to use finish(), If I click on back button from activity B. Activity A will be appear without use of finish(). Am I right?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani ji  .Edited. Then `super.onBackPressed();` is safe

Comment: Ya this will also worked, But If you not override `onBackPressed()` method and click on backbutton that will also work. If first activity is exist.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Ji Agree Agree .

Comment: @ChiragSavsani  i did add that code but after apply that if i click back button exit from app

Comment: @Vishal Then problem is in your Activity A, You may be finish Activity when you go to ActivityB. Post code of Activity A

Comment: next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

No need to put an intent and start a new activity that would take you to previous activity.

Just call 'finish()'

It would go back to previous activity as `Android activities are stored in the activity stack`

If you have other activities that are present in between the activites say if android stack is filled with Activity A>Activity C>Activity B,If you want to go to Activity A on finish of Activityy B then you have to set an   intent flag like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android) no need for intent as A is already in stack and when you finish B, A will come to surface

```
 public void onBackPressed() {

        finish(); 

     }
```

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) to learn more about android activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
            super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: i did add that  code but after apply that if i click back button exit from app

Comment: or put   yourlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); inside the onBackpressed @Vishal

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```