# Android Start Fragment from Activity's back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hello I want to start a Fragment on back-press of Simple Activity

I have done like this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

             Fragment fragment = null;
              fragment = new MainActivity();
             android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);



                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But not working..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Overriding onBackPressed()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


 Fragment fragment = null;
              fragment = new MainActivity();
             android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);



                fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentView, new Fragment()).commit();
}
```