# need to press back button to see the updated ListView in realtime

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

There is a custom `ListView` which populate the data from server using PHP and it is working fine. I have a `notifyDataSetChanged` for list update. But the problem is when there is a change in data on server i need to press back button to see the updated data in the `ListView`. Is there any better way to show the updated list which is similar to WhatsApp list.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seconds);

    contlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contlist);
    startService(new Intent(this, serv.class));

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
        try {
            getNumber(seconds.this.getContentResolver());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.commit();
    } else {
        musers = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);
        descAdapter = new DescAdapter(seconds.this, musers, seconds.this);
        contlist.setAdapter(descAdapter);
     }

    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

    seconds.this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            descAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, intentFilter);
}
```

I am using `intentfilter` in `OnCreate` method for `notifyDataSetChanged`. I placed the intent filter code in the `OnStart`, `OnResume` method also but I need to click back button in order to see the updated list. Any better way to show updated list in realtime ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed

Comment: So you want me to use the Intentfilter code inside the onBackPressed method?

Comment: yes depends on your requirement

Comment: two options, first  option is fcm. whenever something happen on server send push notification and check you are on the page that you want to update and refresh. another option is xmpp or like xmpp protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to refresh the data everytime if some changes happens at the server. But you can implement `Swipe to Refresh` pattern to achieve it without having to press the back button.

I suggest you to go to [this link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/) A basic example of it!

Comment: Hey, I am aware of Swipe to refresh but i need to update the listview in realtime. thanks.

Comment: @user2269164 Never mind! Just wanted to show you the option!