# How to reuse the code in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to reduce the double effort of using the duplicate code. I searched on the google but didn't found about it that how we can reduce the duplication of code in android. May be this question could be stupid but I want the clarification.

**1)** The first thing I want to ask is that how we can reuse the same code in the multiple activity which are being using in overriden method as `onBackPressed()` `onOptionsItemSelected()` and so on. Here is the code which I'm currently writing in the `onBackPressed()` method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(this.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        this.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

For this approache I get the suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed/18337567?noredirect=1#comment86745724_18337567) question to make the base activity then override this method after that extends other activities from that BaseActivity. But how I can pass the `mDrawerLayout` field in the BaseActivity? how I can use `findViewById()` on that base activity to access the xml widgets to access in the overriden method as currently using `mDrawerLayout` layout.

Example in code.

```
public BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; // how to initialize it? where to call findViewById?

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(this.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            this.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

The same question for the `onOptionsItemSelected()` mean menu item actions.

**2)** The second duplication I'm facing about hundred of time is `startActivity()` I have to write `Intent` then add the extra data if required than use that Intent. so about 2 to 3 lines I have to write again and again.

**3)** This thing is about the XML, I'm using the value `5dp` or `10dp` or `10sp` or other `dimen` values in the XML file which are repeating a lot of time. So I want to ask is this approach will be Ok?

```
<dimen name="ten_dp">10dp</dimen>
android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
```

Mean declare the `dp` value then use that in the XML.

**Edited:**

**4)** This problem I have faced now. I'm using the same toolbar in all activities and after adding it in XML layout I have to write this code.

```
private void setupToolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        }
    }
```

But I have to re-write/copy the code in all activities. What is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** For your first question, you'd have to have `mDrawerLayout` in your `BaseActivity`, then you'd attach your child activity's `DrawerLayout` into that field on the child activity's `onCreate()`:

`super.mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)`

You can also do that for other `@Override` methods, such as `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Example based on your `BaseActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }
}
```

Also, make your `BaseAcitivity` abstract to avoid the "add to manifest warning":

`public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

**2)** As for your second question, I'd say that in your `BaseActivity` you could have a public method called `getIntent()` which would return a common `Intent` object. You'd then call that method from your child Activity.

You can pretty much have any method with common functionalities on your `BaseActivity`.

**3)** From my personal experience, it is counterproductive to declare resource values that does not represent the purpose of itself, such as yours: `<dimen name="ten_dp">10dp</dimen>`. I'd rather name it based on a representative use, such as `<dimen name="activity_margin">10dp</dimen>` or whatever.

It is a good practice indeed to have all your hardcoded values (strings, dimens, colors, etc) on your XML resources, you just need to give them significant names (treat them as variable names).

**Edit:**

**4)** Add that method into your `BaseActivity` and pass the `Toolbar` as a param:

```
private void setupToolbar(Toolbar mainToolbar){
    setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it from your `MainActivity` as:

```
Toolbar mainToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
setupToolbar(mainToolbar);
```

Comment: I have updated my question with other problem and the code example for the problem number 1.

Comment: Also If I add the BaseActivity that ask me to register in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Updated my answer in regards to your comments. And about the warning on your AndroidManifest.xml file, just add "abstract" to your BaseActivity

Comment: what if I declare the Toolbar in the BaseActivity and initialize toolbar same as the mDrawerLayout?

Comment: So now two lines are duplicating in all activities. `mainToolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` any more perfect solution? I have found this one. Override `onCreate` method in the base activity then call the `super.onCreate` in the child activity after setting `setContentView()`

Comment: If you do that, then all of your activities that extend from `BaseActivity` would need to have those two views, otherwise you'd get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I know about that. All Activities must have the Toolbar and Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

1- How to get reference to the drawer:
If all activities have drawer in its xml, and with the same Id, then you can use `findViewById` in **BaseActivity**.

```
protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
protected void initNavDrawer() {

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);

}
```

The **BaseActivity** is actually the current running activity, So `findViewById` is totally fine but make sure you have the drawer in all activity, else you will face *NullPointerException*

2- For starting activity, In each activity I add a **static** method which opens the activity

```
    public static void openForEdit(@NonNull Activity context, @NonNull Order order, int requestCode) {
    Intent editOrderIntent = new Intent(context, EditOrderActivity.class);
    editOrderIntent.putExtra(ORDER_TAG, order);
    editOrderIntent.putExtra(EDIT_TAG, true);
    context.startActivityForResult(editOrderIntent, requestCode);
}
```

You can make more than one method if needed.
Then wherever you want to open the activity just call the static method

```
MyActivity.open(//passing parameters);
```

3- About the third point I didn't get exactly your point, But just for clarification: You need to create new xml file called dimens.xml, then you declare your dimens

4- You can put this method in BaseActivity and call it from onCreate in BaseActivity

Comment: 1) - how? any code example? also android hint me to declare the BaseActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Make the BaseActivity abstract class, and don't declare it in Manifest, because you will never open BaseActivity itself

Comment: Great, I'm now managing everything in the BaseActivity, but one problem I'm facing, I have to call super.onCreate() after the setContentView(). I'm initializing `mDrawerLayout` & `toolbar` in the BaseActivity onCreate. So I have to write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. Then BaseActivity will be able to call `findViewById()`, for both variables.

Comment: Do every Activity have the same layout, or different layouts?

Comment: If different layouts, then you will have to call the method initializing `mDrawerLayout` & `toolbar`, in `onCreate` method of every activity extends the base activity