# Manage onBackPressed in single activity android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a single activity app and I want to manage app exit by pressing twice back button. Now I don't know how and where to manage onBack. Would you please help on this?

Comment: you can override onbackpressed() method of activity.
refer below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    if (i == 0){
        i++
        return
    }
    else {
        i = 0
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Activity

```
 private var doublePressToExit = false
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (doublePressToExit) {
        super.onBackPressed()
        return
    }
    this.doublePressToExit = true
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable { doublePressToExit = false }, 2000)  // to reset doublePressToExit to false after 2 sec
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this code in onBackpressed() function of parent activity

```kotlin
  override fun onBackPressed() {
     this.supportFragmentManager
         .primaryNavigationFragment
        ?.findNavController()?.popBackStack()
}
```

**primaryNavigationFragment** provide the instance of the fragment currently displayed on the screen, and from there, we can pop back Stack

```kotlin
this.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

can also work but in that case it destroys the reference of nav direction actions so opening another fragment after closing one would result in a crash with error

```
Navigation component - cannot be found from the current destination
```