# hide keyboard from remote's back button in android TV Leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I was trying to hide the keyboard when the back button is pressed but its actually going back to previous menu when the back button is pressed. What I have is a simple activity with SupportSearchFragment.

```
public class SearchActivity extends LeanbackActivity {
    private SearchFragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        mFragment = (SearchFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.search_fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        mFragment.startRecognition();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The fragment is

```
public class SearchFragment extends SearchSupportFragment
        implements SearchSupportFragment.SearchResultProvider {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setSearchResultProvider(this);

    }

    @Override
    public ObjectAdapter getResultsAdapter() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newQuery) {
        loadQuery(newQuery);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        loadQuery(query);
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is, once the back button is pressed, it should hide the keyboard and then another press of back button, it should go to the previous menu.

What I have found is if the `ArrayObjectAdapter` has any items to show, then back button directly takes to the previous menu. However, if there is no item, it hides the keyboard.

Any suggestion? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First override `onBackPressed` ,[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337567/11718077)

```
override fun onBackPressed(){
    if( view.keyboardIsVisible() )
        this.hideKeyboard()
    else  
        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

Implement your `KeyIsVisible()` , [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63517673/11718077)

```
fun View.keyboardIsVisible() = WindowInsetsCompat
        .toWindowInsetsCompat(rootWindowInsets)
        .isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
```

and Hide Keyboard by

```
/**
 * Use only from Activities, don't use from Fragment (with getActivity) or from Dialog/DialogFragment
 */
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    val view = currentFocus ?: View(this)
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
}
```

Ps , It was too late when I saw your language is java , I have attached refs which will help you converting .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Anshul for your answer. I will just what I exactly needed because the back button always hides the keyboard.

in Activity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment?.isKeyBoardVisible() != true) super.onBackPressed()
}
```

in fragment

```
fun isKeyBoardVisible() = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(requireView())?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: true
```