# How do I use the device back button in my app to go back 1 screen at a time?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to use the built in back button such that it goes back 1 screen within a webview or within the app( no matter where) by 1, so suppose if i have a news section and I click on it, it will display a news page. Then I click on search and go to a webview and when I click on back it should show the news section page i last opened. Also, if I am in the webview and navigate within the webview and click back then it should show me a page within the webview. I have added some back code which works within a webview. However, it does not work for the enws section page. It takes me back to the news section instead of the specific page I opened last under news section. How do I fix my code to achieve the same? Here's the code I added for back:

```
private boolean goingBack = false;
    private boolean onBackPressClearStack = true;

    public void setOnBackPressClearStack(boolean b){
        onBackPressClearStack = b;
    }
    public boolean webViewSteppedBack() {
        if (mWebview != null && mWebview.canGoBack()) {
            mWebview.goBack();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean backPressed(final MainActivity mainActivity) {
        if (webViewSteppedBack()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (onBackPressClearStack) {
            goingBack = true;
            FragmentUtils.onBackPressedKnockFragsOffStack(mainActivity, this);
        }
        return false;
    }
public static MyWebViewFragment newInstanceNoBackPressed(final FragmentManager manager, final String searchTerm,  final String symbolType, int containerViewId) {
        MyWebViewFragment fragment =  __newInstance(new MyWebViewFragment(), manager, searchTerm, symbolType, containerViewId);
        fragment.setOnBackPressClearStack(false);
        return fragment;
    }
public static MyWebViewFragment newInstanceNoBackPressed(final MyWebViewFragment fragment, final FragmentManager manager, final String searchTerm, final String symbolType, int containerViewId) {
        fragment.setOnBackPressClearStack(false);
        return __newInstance(fragment, manager, searchTerm, symbolType, containerViewId);
    }
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.updateActionBarTitle();
        activity.setBackPressListener(this);

        }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (goingBack) {
            return null;
        }
        final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        activity.setBackPressListener(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_answers, container, false);

 my webview code.....
return view;
}
```

Comment: try implementing onbacpressed() method which gets called when you press the device  back button

Comment: no clue how to override my existing function to implement that

Comment: Just implement it like this in your Activity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}

Comment: which activity? I am using fragments and I already have a backpressed function there? can you show it with respect to my code and add the function body which helps to take it back by -1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method that was discussed here: [Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity) if you want to make your own action happen on pressing the back button.

Also you could provide the up navigation as shown here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

I personaly would prefer the second option

Comment: can you explain with respect to my code, that seems a bit confusing for me, new to android sorry.

Comment: You just need the steps mentioned in android developer library (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: That is for navigation and doesnt work in my scenario. I dont have a custom back button but am trying to use the device back button to recognize previous clicks