# ActionBar refresh when back button pressed

Tags: android

I have a button on an action bar that reflects how many items are in the user's favourites. How can I get this to refresh when the back button is pressed?

Comment: use onbackkeypressed method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: replace invalidateOptionsMenu();  with supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); if you are using actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Refresh action bar        
}
```

Comment: That only fires on the current activity? How can I make the activity the user is navigating back to refresh the action bar?

Comment: Set some common variable (global) between the two activities. In this onBackPressed() just set that value. Later when you go back to the other activity, check for this value and then refresh action bar.