# How to detect Hard/Soft back button on Android device?

Tags: android, back-button, back-button-control

I want to know how to detect hard or soft `"BACK Button"` on device? I searched but mostly I found this code

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But I just need to detect if there is BACK button exist on device or not in form of hard or soft.

Comment: Two things. You didn't search first (there are hundreds of answers on here) and you didn't what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Simon can you please provide me links??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

Comment: Well the new coming models has softcopy, otherwise all old phones has hard button only.

Comment: @Simon, Its not an duplicate question.

Comment: @Simon I want to detect Back Button not press Back button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should work

Queries the framework about whether any physical keys exist on the any keyboard attached to the device that are capable of producing the given key code.

```
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

[Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html#deviceHasKey%28int%29)

Comment: great answer, but is possible to know the position of the back button (if is on the right or left)? I want to highlight it with an arrow. If it's software maybe is version check, but if physical I really don't know

Comment: what if the device is using a rom that enables the software keys even when they got the HW ones? Examples are CM, LOS, OxygenOS and so on

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to overide the onBackPress(),becuase whatever the functionality you want to achieve onBackpress key event,you can also do that in onBackPress() method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // do your stuff  here
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by overriding the method

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: I want to to detect Back button on device not to on Click Back Button.