# How can return back to specified fragment in another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four fragments in one viewpager of Activity1, In any of fragment1~4, I open another activity2 by startactivity(Intent), In activity2, I want to return back to previous fragment or other specified fragments, but Now I always return back to the first fragment1 by startactivity(), Any good ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current 'page' and set the current page like this. I guess you could bundle this information when you start activity2 through the intent. Note "FirstFragment" is the name of the activity that sets up my view pager etc with fragments.

```
int currentviewnum =  ((FirstFragment) getActivity()).getPager().getCurrentItem();
```

Once, in activity 2 and you want to return back to it, or another view pager (currentviewnum), you could do something like this in an override for the back button (see here for that [Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)); But you can do something like this!

((FirstFragment) getActivity()).getPager().setCurrentItem(currentviewnum);

So effectively when you press the back button, let me know if this works. I do something like this in my app. But instead of going back, it's more to go to the next one!