# Disable Back Button (onBackPressed)

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to disable back button from closing the app. 
How can i disable back button?

Comment: Please read [the relevant Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) with regard to your implementation.

Comment: Please don't do this!

Comment: We discourage the use of disabling the back button and replacing it with an exit button on the screen, because it is a distraction. The user is accustomed to the standards of having the app close when they press the back button. Don't over-complicate a simple function. Check out the guidelines like Ollie suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method and determine what happens in that method. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing because you don't want them to leave when it's pressed
}
```

Just add that method to your activity class and you're good to go.

However, this is bad app design. What you would most likely want to do is make a dialog pop up that asks them if they are sure they want to leave. You would add the dialog code inside that method so that when the back button is pressed, the dialog pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, that's not a good idea. Users hate to feel "trapped" in your app.

Many users are able to start apps "on top of" other apps. When they hit "back" they may expect your app to stop, and the app they were in previously to appear. This is different from "home" where they expect all apps to go to the background.

Users familiar and comfortable with this functionality will not like it if you change "back" - although you may give them options like "press back again to exit" as some apps do. It depends on your particular situation.

So if you are in need of it, here is a good reference:

[Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

Comment: I edited my answer to explain "trapped" - in some rare cases, you need to override "back" and the functionality is there to do it. Just try to think of other options...