# Proper navigation between activities using navigation drawer and back button?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have the following situation:

One Main `ListActivity`. The list consists of POJO objects, each item is a different POJO.

Each POJO contains different groups. For each group I made different `Activity`.

Lets say POJO1 contains groups **A**, **B** and **C**, when pressed, **ActivityA** will be opened and the navigation between the rest activities **ActivityB** and **ActivityC** is done using `NavigationDrawer`.

All group activities implement a custom class **MyNavigationDrawerClass** which is the core of the `Navigation Drawer` in my app.

Each **ActivityA**, **B**, **C**, etc, has a **SettingsActivity** which is strictly individual and depends on from where it has been started.

Now the question is: How to navigate from any **A**, **B**, **C**, etc, activity to the Main ListActivity every time the `BackButton` is pressed?

I will provide an example:

1. App is started - **Main List Activity** is showed;
2. Item is pressed and **ActivityA** with `NavigationDrawer` is started;
3. The `NavigationDrawer` is opened and **ActivityC** is opened;
4. When `BackButton` is pressed, the user is navigated  back to **ActivityA**, but my desire is to navigate the user to the **Main List Activity**

What I tried:

1. To put `android:noHistory="true"` for every  **ActivityA**, **ActivityB** and **ActivityC** in the `AndroidManifest`. That did not work because when I open the **SettingsActivity** for example from **ActivityA** and return, the user in navigated to the **Main List Activity**, and not to the **ActivityA** - it's confusing and misleading.
2. To override `onBackPressed` in **MyNavigationDrawerClass** and start the **Main List Activity** using `Intent`. That did not work either because there are still previous activities in the stack and when the `BackButton` is pressed from **Main List Activity**, the user is navigated to them.

I hope I explained the situation clearly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `public void onBackPressed(){...}` for redirect the user where you want like this :

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);    
}
```

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity) can help you

Comment: Hi, this is not what I'm looking for, it doesn't work for me, thanks for the answer!

Comment: what does happen when you use this method ?