# Fragment is not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tabhost

I am using navigation drawer in my app,everything working fine,the issue is onbackpress my app getting close,there is no crash of app,just my app is closing

Following is my code and screen shot ,can anyone help?

MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();

                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FriendsFragment();


                title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MessagesFragment();


                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;

            case 3:
                fragment = new Profiles();


                title = getString(R.string.title_pro);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_aboutus);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new FAQ();
                title = getString(R.string.title_faq);
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new Privacypolicy();
                title = getString(R.string.title_privacypolicy);
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new ContactUs();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contacts);
                break;

            case 8:
                // session.logoutUser();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
               // Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginPage.class);
                // startActivity(intent);
                title = getString(R.string.title_logout);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            //additional code
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

    }*/

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        } else {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private SearchView searchView;
    // private String strtext;
    // private String FBIDs;
    // private String GIDs;


    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.my_parent_fragment);
        // strtext = getArguments().getString("user_login_id");


        //  System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Session ID :  " + strtext);

        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
        arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
       /* if(strtext!=null) {
            arg1.putString("user_logid", strtext);
        }*/

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_profile_tabs, "Home")), DiscoverFragment.class, arg1);
        Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();

        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);

       /* if(strtext!=null) {
            arg2.putString("user_logid_sectab", strtext);
        }*/

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Sec").
                setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_frnds_tab, "Invite")), ShopFragment.class, arg2);


        Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
        arg3.putInt("Arg for Frag3", 3);

      /*  if(strtext!=null) {
            arg3.putString("user_logid_thirdtab", strtext);
        }*/

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").
                setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_wish_tab, "Wish")), Thirdtab.class, arg3);


        Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
        arg4.putInt("Arg for Frag4", 4);
        /*if(strtext!=null) {
            arg4.putString("user_logid_fourthtab", strtext);
        }*/

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Four").
                setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_notification_tab, "Alert")), FourthTabs.class, arg4);

        return tabHost;


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public View getTabIndicator(Context context, int icon, String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.indicatorImageView);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttb);
        txt.setText(text);
        return view;
    }


}
```

DiscoverFragment.java

```
public class DiscoverFragment extends Fragment {


    private Button btn;

    public DiscoverFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_frag, container, false);

        btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnhomf);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WishaFriend ff = new WishaFriend();

                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
               // ft.replace(R.id.container_body,ff);
               ft.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), ff);

                // fm.addToBackStack("sds");
               ft.commit();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

when i run app it shows this as first screen

[image]

then i click on gotonextfrag button,and it will redirect to next frag and i am getting this screen

[image]

now from this fragment if i press backbutton of device my app get close

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/MyToolBarStyle.Base"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"

                android:src="@drawable/toolbartitle"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <!-- activity view -->
        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- navigation drawer -->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.balloons.balloonationn.activity.FragmentDrawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You mean you , when you back press you want to show your previous fragment?

Comment: Then you should maintain your all fragments in fragment arraylist or you can set tag and on back press find with that tag. Like `findByFragmentTag("urStrTag")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the normal behavior of Activity. When you press back button, it finish the current activity.

[Override back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

Comment: i want to manage fragments..dint you see that Homefragment has four tabs,,

Comment: you'll have to handle back button programmatically to navigate back to the previous fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not adding to `BackStack`.

Try this when you want to show a `fragment`

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dashboard_container, fragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
        setActionBarTitle(title);
        if (backStateName == DashBoardFragment.class.getSimpleName()) {
            clearBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

and in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    } else {
        int backStackCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (backStackCount > 0) {
            popFragments(backStackCount);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void popFragments(int backStackCount) {
    String fragmentTag = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(
            backStackCount - 1).getName();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fragmentTag)) {
        Fragment currentFragment = mFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.dashboard_container);
        if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }
}

private void clearBackStack() {
    mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    setSelectedItem(Numerics.ZERO);
}
```

Comment: add it in your Activity and when you want to show a fragment just send like `WishFragment ff = new WishFragment(); 
showFragment(ff, "Wish Fragment");`

Comment: i added your showFragment in main activity it shows cannot resolve clearBackStack

Comment: see I added that method

Comment: please replace that with your drawerlayout

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your fragmentTransaction.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code,

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("messages"); /** Add this line**/
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

this will add the fragment in your backstack which is not happening in your case.

In your onBackPressed

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // if drawer is open
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {

            if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)
                Log.d(TAG,"fragment count = 0 "); /** here your fragment count is 0. Add alert to exit app **/
            else
               super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i did that on back my tabhost become invisible

Comment: can you share your xml file where your  container_body contains

Comment: try this replace your onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Fragment as below -

   ```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.myFrame, new FirstFrag(), null)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit();
   ```
2. Change your onBackPressed() mth as below

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed(){
       FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

       if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
           fm.popBackStack();

       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @Jolly: check my answer see if it helps.