# Checking if we came from Android Back Button

Tags: android

I have a Android application that looks like this:

> LoginActivity -> MainActivity

My Android problem is that if we have successfully logged in (we are at MainActivity), then press the Back Button on the phone, we will go back to LoginActivity. That doesn't make any sense, because we are logged in.

How can I check in LoginActivity if we came from Back Button? I tried this code, but it doesnt help, because onCreate is not run when coming from Back Button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Check if we are registered before, then just go to Main
    checkIfWeAreRegistered();
}
```

Comment: finish your loginActivity when you proceed to mainActivity

Comment: in which activity you want to go on back button click

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity

Comment: Thank you  Subhechhu Khanal. That worked for me!

Comment: Javascript way which worked for me in my previous hybrid app projects is this: BackButton.override();

Comment: Your main Activity should be set as the DEFAULT one. And the login Activity as the LAUNCHER one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it just simple just call `finish()` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

or try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before  start main activity  just finish LoginActivity once login success.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.class, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

other wise 
Activity 2 customized onBackPressed in MainActivity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

// do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for the `onBackPressed` call in your `LoginActivity` you can set in the manifest `noHistory=true` to remove it from the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

You can uses startActivtyForResult() for activity transition and handle onActivityResult in your login activity. An you close the activity from this override method.

Note: You should call setResult(RESULT_OK) form back button press from your mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in onBackPressed method in MainActivity if you have already registrited. If so do not go to LoginActivty.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here 
     super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Solo,

Once you go from `LoginActivity` to `MainActivity` your `LoginActivity` goes to backstack and hence on clicking on the back button in `MainActivity` it calls the `LoginActivity` again from backstack, in which it calls `onStart()` method.

There are multiple way by which you can avaoid user going back to `LoginActivity` from `MainActivity`

**First**

finish `LoginActivity` after you call `MainActivity`

so for example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // will finish that activity.
```

**Second**

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Here `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` clears the stack and makes it the top one.So when we press back button the whole application will be terminated.