# Can I change what the back arrow at the bottom of the screen does?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, back

Can I change what that button does. I tried just using it but when the user changes something and goes back, the changes aren't applied

[image]

Comment: Do you have a programming language?  Tag it appropriately.

Comment: It's in java, for android studio

Comment: Use the edit link under your question to fill out the tags appropriately.

Comment: You can check correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just override `onBackPress` of your activity.
Check documentation for more info - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()

Comment: So for every activity, is there a onBackPress function?

Comment: I've tried overriding the onBackPress. It gives me an error saying "Annotations are not allowed here"

Comment: 1st comment - yes. 2nd comment - can you provide your code? seems like it is not the method override problem

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. The problem was that I was trying to override it in the onCreate() method. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for it?

[Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3141996/6026739)

you can override `onBackPressed()` method in your activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
      //  super.onBackPressed()
        Toast.makeText(this,"Back Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```