# How to use InputConnectionWrapper?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, user-input

I have an `EditText`. Now I want to get all changes made by the user to this `EditText` and work with them before manually inserting them into the `EditText`. I don't want the user to directly change the text in the `EditText`. This should only be done by my code (e.g. by using `replace()` or `setText()`).

I searched a bit and found an interesting class named `InputConnectionWrapper`. According to the javadoc it shall act as a proxy for a given `InputConnection`. So I subclassed it like this:

```
private class EditTextInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public EditTextInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
                    // some code which takes the input and manipulates it and calls editText.getText().replace() afterwards
        return true;
    }

}
```

To initialize the wrapper I overwrote the following method in my `EditText`-subclass:

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    InputConnection con = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
    EditTextInputConnection connectionWrapper = new EditTextInputConnection(con, true);
    return connectionWrapper;
}
```

However, `commitText()` never gets called. The `onCreateInputConnection()` gets called and the constructor of `EditTextInputConnection` also, but never `commitText()`, altough it should be, when I enter some text into the field. At least, that's how I understand the usage of `InputConnectionWrapper`. Or am I wrong?

**Edit:** It seems, that `commitText()` is only called for special characters like "."," " etc. As I understand the Android sourcecode for all other characters `InputConnectionWrapper.sendKeyEvent()` should be called, but that's not the case... I'm absolutely stuck at this point. I already tried `EditText.onKeyPreIme()`, but this only works on hardware keyboards. So that's no alternative... I don't really understand, why Android handles soft keyboards that different from hardware keyboards.
`EditText.onTextChanged()` gets also fired on non-user input, so this is also not, what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out, that the above usage of the `InputConnectionWrapper` was totally correct. However, `commitText()` gets never called (except for special cases), as there are other methods, which are used during typing. These are mainly `setComposingText()` and `sendKeyEvent()`. However, it is also important to overwrite seldom used methods like `deleteSurroundingText()` or `commitText()` to make sure to catch **every** user input.

Comment: This doesn't prevent user from copy-pasting random text into EditText, but works for everything else.

Comment: @ubuntudroid Hi, do you know which methods need to be overwritten to capture all inputs? Including copy pasting.

Comment: @what_is_sleep As Alexey pointed out correctly, you can't capture copy-pasting with this method, sorry. Maybe ´Text Watcher´ can help you handling this case?

Answer (score 1):

[Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell) suggested on the chat that you use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Check if this helps you out.

Comment: The problem with a TextWatcher is, that I cannot determine the source of input there (i.e. keyboard input or input directly from my code). It would also be notified, if I changed the text by EditText.getText().replace() or EditText.setText(), I assume.

Comment: I'm not sure, have you tested it?

Comment: It should be like this, as getText().replace()/insert() operates directly on the Editable behind the EditText. So the TextWatcher which tracks the changes of the Editable will be notified on any change of the Editable. I'm currently working on another solution which incorporates a subclass of Editable and special methods to access it from code and overwritten methods for insert() and replace(). Will post my findings here once it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Use a TextWatcher, disconnect it when you're modifying your edittext and reconnect it when done. This way, you won't trigger infinite calls.