# Android Application Lifecycle

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-lifecycle, background-foreground

I see a lot of answers concerning the Activity Lifecycle and that for most part is clear to me. What I'm looking for is the Application Lifecycle. I have the following case:

1. Application starts - Invalidate PIN
2. A PIN has to be entered if it is stale of invalid
3. Application is backgrounded (Android Home screen is visible) - Invalidate PIN
4. The applicatiion is foregrounded (App becomes visible again) - goto step 2

With the Activity Lifecycle it is hard if not impossible to achieve. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you mean backgrounded, you mean that the application is no longer visible, right?

Comment: Right, that is what I mean

Comment: Hard to undrstand what exactly are you looking for, but I would suggest looking at Android Services: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Which part do you not understand. Is the description not clear enough?

Comment: Ye sorry. Look at this Q&A. Specifically the most upvoted answer. (not the accepted one) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573121/940834

Comment: The problem is that activity code is called over and over again for each activity becoming active of being stopped. As long as the Application is active there is no need to enter a new PIN but when the App is pushed to the background and later resumed I want the user to enter a PIN again for security reasons.

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned I'm using Xaramin with C# and Visual Studio

Comment: The Application itself doesn't have much of a lifecycle. It is created then killed. You need to monitor all Activities in order to determine if one of them is visible at a given time. You can make them all inherit from a base Activity in order to make it easier.

Comment: @Doomsknight: It is a dirty hack. Is there no cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Another interesting method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999738/940834 Which may be seen as cleaner.. not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the solution Doomsknight pointed me to I constructed this solution without the Timer as proposed in the proposed answer. Here's the code from my mainapplication.cs:

```
    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
        _lastActivity = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = now - _lastActivity;

        if (span.TotalMilliseconds > 2000)
        {
            Notifier.Classes.Settings.IsPinValid = false;
        }

        _lastActivity = now;
    }
```

Comment: Nicely done. You should mark it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

When your application is backgrounded (no longer visible), the method called is `onStop()`, and when the application is foregrounded, `onStart()` and then `onResume()` will be called (`onCreate()` could be called as well).

The thing is, what you should do is invalidate PIN in `onStop()`, and then ask for the PIN in `onResume()`. This will always make your application ask for the PIN: the first time the application starts and whenever it is backgrounded.

Comment: This will occur during activity transition. Aka, Activity A -> B

Comment: @Doomsknight: Exactly, that is my problem.

Comment: Ah, than you should have mentioned it in the question

Comment: That is what I did mention: "With the Activity Lifecycle it is hard if not impossible to achieve"

Comment: I guess you can always check a value (e.g. `SharedPreferences`) and decide whether you have to introduce the PIN or not according to its state (e.g. a boolean)

Answer (score 0):

1. Application starts - `onCreate()`/ `onStart()`
2. Get the pin in `onCreate` or `onStart` or `onResume()` (check the state of the pin.

3.Application is backgrounded - `onPause()` - Invalidate your pin on onPause() method

4.The applicatiion is foregrounded - `onResume()` - perform step 2 in onResume()

Comment: I would not invalidate the PIN in `onPause()`, because the application could be partially visible, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter because you are going to validate again in onResume()

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here. The OnStart() and OnStop() are called for every activity. It does not say anything about the Application being push/popped from the background.

Comment: Could this have something to do with MvvmCross? I use the ShowViewModel() method to show a new view.