# Application should give a prompt on pressing back button

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I wish that when I press back button in my application, it should give me a prompt(kind of alert dialog) if I really wish to exit.
I dont know where to put this alert dialog and what to write in the Yes button, where user wants to quit the application. Please help me.

Comment: This question has been asked a lot [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550505/override-android-back-button) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969541/override-the-back-button-in-android) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override `OnBackPressed()` Function.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Exit");
    builder.setMessage("Are You Sure?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
            }
        });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Although every thing seems fine with this answer, it is not advisable to use System.exit(0); in android.

Comment: Cheers, did the job for me :-D

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        AppDemoActivity.this);

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
    }
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);

alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
alertDialog.setTitle("AppTitle");
alertDialog.show();
}
```

Use this to show an alert on Back Pressed

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to Override Back button :

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `onBackPressed` to show the alert, and in the `yes` button `finish` the activity..

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //show alert here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    private void onBackPressed() {

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you really want to exit?");
alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                ThisActivity.this.finish();
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });             
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
        alertDialog.show();
  }
```