# Preventing the back button from cancelling a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, fragment, back-button

I have a Fragment that can create and pop up a DialogFragment, but when I hit the back button, it dismisses the dialog even though I explicitly call setCancelable(false); Is there any way for my DialogFragment to be insensative to the back button?

```
public class LoadingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    String title;
    String msg;

    public LoadingDialogFragment()
    {
        this.title = "Loading...";
        this.msg = "Please wait...";
    }
    public LoadingDialogFragment(String title, String msg)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(msg);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

I create the DialogFragment from an AsyncTask:

```
private class GpsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
{
    //ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DialogFragment newFragment = new LoadingDialogFragment("Gathering Location", "Acquiring GPS lock...");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        //acquire a GPS lock and grab a few position updates
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... input) { }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

How about using [`setCancelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29)? Did you try it?

**From the Docs:**

> Control whether the shown Dialog is cancelable. Use this instead of
> directly calling Dialog.setCancelable(boolean), because DialogFragment
> needs to change its behavior based on this

**For custom DialogFragment**

Add `isCancelable = false` at `onCreateDialog`

Comment: This is correct! it turns out you have to call setCancelable(false) on the DialogFragment itself, not the inner Dialog that it holds!

Comment: @MattF This comment is a life saver. Did not realize i needed to call `setCancelable()` on the `DialogFragment` instead of the `ProgressDialog`. Thanks!

Comment: I used `isCancelable = false` in Kotlin, inside of `onViewCreated` and it worked!!

Comment: It works for me too @Seven, i use isCancelable = false (not dialog.setCancelable(false))

Comment: I was using ```getDialog.setCancelable(false)``` and it didn't work, but I replaced it with ```setCancelable(false)``` and it works correctly. that's was weird

Comment: For custom DialogFragment add isCancelable = false at onCreateDialog

Answer (score 9):

```
 DialogFragment newFragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
                newFragment.setCancelable(false);
                newFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, "dialog");
```

Add setCancelable(false) before you .Show() the fragment

Comment: GREAT tip. And here's an important further point on that http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480564/294884

Answer (score 4):

I'm not at all sure if this'll work with FragmentDialogs, but if the setCancelable didn't work for you, it might be worth having a look at this article: [Android: Prompt user to save changes when Back button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459848/android-prompt-user-to-save-changes-when-back-button-is-pressed)

It explains how to detect the back button being pressed. So maybe you can suppress the button press and it'll stop the dialog from closing?

Comment: I ended up going with the other answer but I do think this works as well, many thanks

Answer (score 3):

`onCreateDialog` vs `onCreateView`:

> Implementations should override this class and implement
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) to supply the content
>   of the dialog. Alternatively, they can override onCreateDialog(Bundle)
>   to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an AlertDialog, with its
>   own content.

Important when using `onCreateDialog`:

> Override to build your own custom Dialog container. This is typically
>   used to show an AlertDialog instead of a generic Dialog; when doing
>   so, onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) does **not** need to
>   be implemented since the AlertDialog takes care of its own content.

Example `Dialog` (In this case an `AlertDialog`):

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setCanceble(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

The property `setCanceble(boolean)` states whether you can exit the `Dialog` with a back press. No need to catch the KEYCODE_BACK anywhere.

Comment: This does not work. You have to call `setCancelable(boolean)` on the `DialogFragment`, not on the `Dialog` which is what you are doing now.

Answer (score 3):

It may help you.

```
newFragment.setCancelable(false);
```

make changes like above when creating DialogFragment object or in the constructor of Custom DialogFragment as in the sample below.

```
public static CustomClearHourDialog newInstance(Bundle args, IDialogListener listener)
        {
            CustomClearHourDialog clearHourDialog = new CustomClearHourDialog();            
            CustomClearHourDialog.listener = listener;
            clearHourDialog.setCancelable(false);
            return clearHourDialog;
        }
```