# Dismiss Dialog Fragment when pressed outside

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

I use Dialog Fragment I extend it

```
public class DocumentLibrarySelectionFragment extends DialogFragment
```

I am not sure how to dismiss this dialog when the user presses outside it (I show this dialog inside my activity). I went through other related questions, but couldn't find complete answer, for example this [How to dismiss a DialogFragment when pressing outside the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404140/how-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-when-pressing-outside-the-dialog) here, where to add this lines of code in the first answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `onCreateView`, you can add `DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    ... 
}
```

Comment: To add this method in my DialogFragment implementation or? I have @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) { method only in my fragment implementation?

Comment: As Blackbelt said (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480564/6444297), instead of 'getDialog().setCancelable(false);' you have to use directly 'setCancelable(false);'