# Focusing on the same button after coming back to main activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I am trying to do a simple thing in my app.

There are three button that take the user to three different screen. Once the user clicks the button and comes back to the activity I want the focus to stay on the button that the user had left before.

I tried saved instance state but its not working.

Comment: You could place the location of the button in the intent that you fire off to the new Activity. It's kind of a hack, but I guess it works. Why do you want/need the button to retain focus?

Comment: @ user1106888 could this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459848/android-prompt-user-to-save-changes-when-back-button-is-pressed solve your query?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same in one of my apps.

`btn1`,`btn2`,`btn3` are 3 buttons in main activity. On click of them, I'm navigating to deifferent activities.

`btnenable`(the red one) and `btndisable`(the grey one) are two images used for displaying highlighted button.

---

This is the snapshot:
[image: snapshot]

---

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnenable);
    btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btndisable);
    btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btndisable);
}
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnenable);
    btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btndisable);
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btndisable);
}
});

btn3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnenable);
    btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btndisable);
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btndisable);
}
});
```

Hope it hepls !!!
Feel free to ask your query !!

Comment: i am using image buttons can you help