# AND operator is not working for onKeyUp method

Tags: java, android

Hi, I wish to know why the `AND` operator is not working here? Even though without operator it working fine what is wrong while including it?

```
else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
    int visibility=new_Sell_order_cart.getVisibility();
    if(visibility==View.VISIBLE)
    {
        openCart(); 
    }
}
```

If its not possible how jQuery developer Achive this

```
        if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('ctrl A');
    }
});
```

Comment: are u looking for OR operator? AND will return false when either or both of the statements are `false`...

Comment: How do you expect `keyCode` to be equal to two different things?

Comment: Unless you have a quantum computer, keyCode cannot have two different values at the same time

Comment: I want to perform a task with click on LEFT_CTRL and s both.

Comment: @BlueGreen Then go for OR operator...

Comment: @GopalRao,, if i used OR then it will work s or crlt but i want only for ctrl+s only

Comment: @BlueGreen: I haven't done Android programming before but I'm assuming that you're getting the keycode from a KeyEvent, correct? Wouldn't you want to check another property of the event such as its [meta state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()) as well?

Comment: hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14079494/2764279) helps you

Answer (score 1):

keyCode cannot be two keys at once. It can be either CTRL_LEFT or KEYCODE_S.

This statement returns false because either one will be true but not both.

(Its like `a==3 && a==4`, a cannot be 3 and 4 at the same time)

```
keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S
```

Probably you are looking for OR `(||)` operator:

```
 else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
```

EDIT:

If you want to check for two keypress. Here is the solution suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753078/2741586) post.

> One way would be to keep track yourself of what keys are currently
>   down.
>
> When you get a keyPressed event, add the new key to the list; when you
>   get a keyReleased event, remove the key from the list.
>
> Then in your game loop, you can do actions based on what's in the list
>   of keys.

Answer (score 0):

I got one Solution , I know it is not up-to mark but it full-fill my requirement .

```
       else if (isCTRLisPressed(17) && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
        int visibility=new_Sell_order_cart.getVisibility();     
        if(visibility==View.VISIBLE)
        {
            openCart(); 
        }
    }
```

and

```
   public boolean isCTRLisPressed(int i){
if(i==17){
    System.out.println(" key code of ctrl"+i);
    return true;
}
else {
    System.out.println("key code in else "+i);
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: So whats the use of AND operator here? directly u are hardcoding here and returning `true` when value is 17... so you are condition now becomes `if(true && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S)` where `&&` operator is useless...

Comment: Something like that,,,that's why i told "not up-to mark"