# Android app disappearing from running processes

Tags: android, hide

I have a problem with android application which disappears from running processes after going back to android start screen. I don't know where the problem might be. Please help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you've set an empty title for your activity in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

In android, when you press the back hard key, an activity is closed.
When the home hard key is pressed, the activity is pushed to the background.

Check this out.
[Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

[Android: Prompt user to save changes when Back button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459848/android-prompt-user-to-save-changes-when-back-button-is-pressed)